# How to access twitter filter search stream api on ios

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

This is the approach I am using to get the tweets via twitter new v2 filter [search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/introduction) after getting the bearer token.

```
static func callFilterSearch() {
    let Url = String(format: "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream?place.fields=contained_within&user.fields=location&tweet.fields=geo")
    guard let serviceUrl = URL(string: Url) else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("Bearer MY BEARER TOKEN", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("gzip, deflate, br", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")
    request.setValue("keep-alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
    request.setValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("v2FilteredStreamPython", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    sessionConfig.networkServiceType = .responsiveData
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let teamJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments, .fragmentsAllowed, .mutableContainers, .mutableLeaves])
                print("teamJSON: \(teamJSON)")
            } catch let error {
                print("error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Unfortunately I am not successful in getting the tweets this way. However the python client that twitter has put in [github repo](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/main/Filtered-Stream/filtered_stream.py) seems to work just fine and is spewing tweets as expected.

Please help me out here

Comment: What error does your code produces?